# Make border-right full height of div

Tags: css, html, border

I had a problem concerning border-right in my menu. This is what it looks like:[link](http://abload.de/image.php?img=immobilienverwaltungb0mq80.png) I would like to have the border take up the whole blue bar, not extending below
 it, but touching the edge at the top. how could I do this? my code is this:

```
#container #header #metaNavi{
height:58px;
background: #bbd4eb; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbd4eb 0%, #76a8d6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#bbd4eb),   color-   stop(100%,#76a8d6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbd4eb 0%,#76a8d6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbd4eb 0%,#76a8d6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbd4eb 0%,#76a8d6 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bbd4eb 0%,#76a8d6 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bbd4eb',      endColorstr='#76a8d6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
position:relative;
top:455px;
font-size:20px
}
#container #header #metaNavi ul{
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style:none;
}
#container #header #metaNavi li{
display:inline-block;
padding:8px 25px 10px 10px;
margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
color:#bf7a30;
font-family:Verdana;
font-variant:small-caps;
border-right: 1px solid #717171;
min-height:58px;
max-height:58px;
}
#container #header #metaNavi li:last{ 
border-right: none
```

My Html is:

```
    <div id="metaNavi">
    <ul>
    <li id="active">Home</li>
    <li><a href="#">Wir über Uns</li></a>
    <li><a href="#">Dienstleistungen</li></a>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</li></a>
    </ul>
```

demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=GA5vE7nrgv

Comment: It would help if you made a small jsfiddle demonstrating the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

you must edit this line `#container #header #metaNavi li`

add -> `line-height: 55px;`
remove -> `padding: 8px 25px 10px 10px;`
add ->   `padding: 0 25px 0 10px;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

I removed the margin, adding padding to space along the x-axis and changed min/max-height to just height. Then targeted the active within the list-item so that it is a block level element at 100% width and 58 pixels height. The line-height on the list item, centers it vertically.

```
#metaNavi:before,
#metaNavi:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} 
#metaNavi:after {
    clear: both;
}
#metaNavi {
    zoom: 1; /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
#container #header #metaNavi{
    height:58px;
    background: #bbd4eb; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #bbd4eb 0%, #76a8d6 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#bbd4eb), color-stop(100%,#76a8d6)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #bbd4eb 0%,#76a8d6 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #bbd4eb 0%,#76a8d6 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #bbd4eb 0%,#76a8d6 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #bbd4eb 0%,#76a8d6 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bbd4eb', endColorstr='#76a8d6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    position:relative;
    top:455px;
    font-size:20px
}
#container #header #metaNavi ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
#container #header #metaNavi li{
    display:block;
    float: left;
    padding:0 20px;
    color:#bf7a30;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-variant:small-caps;
    border-right: 1px solid #717171;
    height:58px;
    line-height: 58px;
}
#metaNavi ul li a{
    display: block;   
    width: 100%;
    height: 58px;
}
#container #header #metaNavi li:last{ 
    border-right: none
}
#container #header #metaNavi li a{
    color:#bf7a30;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#container #header #metaNavi #active{
    color:#333333;
    font-weight:800;
}
```